# Reload video after new source file in MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, web

I am working on a web service (using ASP.NET MVC), where I need to display two videos. These two videos are regularly updated.

The models used in the MVC project simply store the path to the videos (would it be a better idea to have the video files in the model?).

I expected that, after changing the video files (new .mp4 files, keeping the old path) and reloading, the videos would change, but this is not the case.

How can I make my videos update? So far I have tried creating an HTML function with "load()", similarly as [in this link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_load.asp), but it does not work. (Also I am not sure this would be a good solution for me, since I need to force the update from the controller.)

Thank you!

Edit: Adding some code, as requested in the comments.

The model (yes, the name is old, I will change it to "video"):

```
public class Picture
{
    public int PictureID { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string PicName { get; set; }
    public int Xsize { get; set; }
    public int Ysize { get; set; }

    public Picture()
    {
        FilePath = "../../VideoDatabase/";
        PicName = "Default";
        Xsize = 320;
        Ysize = 200;
    }

    public void LinkNameAndPath()
    {
        FilePath = "../../VideoDatabase/" + PicName + ".mp4";
    }
}
```

In the controller, creating a model object:

```
    Picture CreateDefault(string pictureName)
    {
        Picture picture = new Picture();
        picture.FilePath += "Candidates/" + pictureName + ".mp4";
        picture.PicName = pictureName;
        return picture;
    }
```

In the controller, calling the view:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        if (candidates.Count != 2)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("UnexpectedError");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(candidates);
        }
    }
```

In the view, the video object:

```
        <video id="candidate0video" width="432" height="240" controls autoplay loop>
            <source src=@Model[0].FilePath type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
```

Comment: Maybe you need `Ctrl+F5` instead of `F5`, just guessing. Please show what you'v done and with that i mean show your code.

Comment: I tried Ctrl+F5, but it did not work. I will try to show some of the code, but it is quite a large project, so it is not trivial to know what will be more relevant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine offered useful insight into the matter. I translate (and adapt) here what he said, which is the base of my solution to the problem (basically solved by using new names for the files that were updated):

It is complicated. The first time you download an asset, the server adds a header HTTP "Cache-control" to tell the client to cache locally the file during some given time.

The idea is that you want active caches to reduce the load on your server. (Maybe in a development environment it makes sense to deactivate the cache.)

The typical solution is to change the name of the files automatically adding the hash of the contents of the file. This way, if you have a text file (CSS/JS) clients will download the new version when you update the content.

I recommend you to look for a library that manages that automatically (supposing the videos are uploaded through your app and not using FTP directly).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to debug your view model first. That way, you will be able to tell whether or not the view model is getting the correct values. If the file path is not updated correctly, then obviously the video won't display right on the page.

You probably should also check these things as well

- Did the `pictureName` parameter get passed in successfully?
- What about the method `LinkNameAndPath()`? Did it actually get called or not?

Update

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("[Your file path]");
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=[your file name].mp4");
    var objFile = new FileInfo(path);
    var stream = objFile.OpenRead();
    var objBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(objBytes, 0, (int)objFile.Length);
    HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(objBytes);
}

<video id="candidate0video" width="432" height="240" controls autoplay loop>
   <source src=@Url.Action("Index","[your controller name]") type="video/mp4">
   <!-- or try the following -->
   <!-- <source src=@Url.Content(Model[0].FilePath) type="video/mp4"> -->
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for contributing!
The thing is that what I am changing is not the path to a new video file, but the video file at the end of the old path!
(But I can confirm that LinkNameAndPath works correctly and that pictureName is passed correctly as well.)

Comment: @Pablo added the code example, perhaps give it a try

Comment: I'm heading off for the day now, but I will try to see if I can make that piece of code work and solve the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have been trying to apply the code, but it's not working properly (perhaps I have simply done something wrong, I have very little experience with MVC). If I copy directly your code I get a complaint that there is not a return value for the ActionResult Index(). If I return a view after your code, the view will not load. The code itself downloads an instance of the video (did you expect this to happen or is that my fault?)

Comment: @Pablo you could possibly try `@Url.Content(Model[0].FilePath)` instead and see if that works for you or not.

Comment: I believe the problem is more fundamental and has to do with caches, so I have been recommended to try not only updating the video files, but also their names when I do this. I am currently working on that approach, and I will let you know what comes out of that.